# How to preload images with cached_network_image?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've just implemented the Flutter *package cached_network_image* and I wonder how I can preload images so they're available later in an instant. I retrieve all image-urls that will be used later from the our server.

I've defined my custom cache manager getter:

```
class LocalCacheManager {
  static const key = 'customCacheKey';
  static CacheManager instance = CacheManager(
    Config(
      key,
      stalePeriod: const Duration(days: 14),
      maxNrOfCacheObjects: 200,
      repo: JsonCacheInfoRepository(databaseName: key),
      fileSystem: LocalCacheFileSystem(key),
      fileService: HttpFileService(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Here's how I currently try to preload the image:

```
LocalCacheManager.instance.downloadFile(MY_IMAGE_URL)),
```

And here's how I create the widget:

```
child: CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl: MY_IMAGE_URL, cacheManager: LocalCacheManager.instance),
```

But I can clearly see that files are always cached again as soon as I create the CachedNetworkImage.

Comment: I must admit that my solution works... I use another package that displays the images with a fade-in animation, that's why I don't see much difference.

So if anyone wants to know how to pre-load cached network images, there you go.

Answer (score 14):

You can use [Flutter Cache Manager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager) like this

```
DefaultCacheManager().downloadFile(MY_IMAGE_URL).then((_) {});
```

Later, just use your cached image like this

```
child: CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl: MY_IMAGE_URL,),
```

Answer (score 10):

Simplest and workable way is to use precacheImage (flutter build-in function) with CachedNetworkImageProvider:

```
Image image = Image(
        image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(/* url */),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      );

      precacheImage(image.image, context);

      return Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                child: image,
              ),
            );
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this bro:

`precacheImage(CachedNetworkImageProvider(imageUrl), context);`

It's built in Flutter https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/precacheImage.html, no need to install more libraries