# how to preload images from an json.decode

Tags: flutter, dart, preload

Im trying to make my images i get from a json file to preload but i cant seem to get this to work,
I saw another post on stackoverflow mentioning precacheImage in the initState() but i cant get this to work with my readJson() method. i basically want to preload the image i get from this json.

code

```
class _KillerRouteState extends State<KillerRoute> {
  List _items = [];

  // Fetch content from the json file
  Future<void> readJson() async {
    final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/dbdKillers.json');
    final data = await json.decode(response);
    setState(() {
      _items = data["killers"];
    });
  }

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    readJson();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(58, 66, 86, 1.0),
      appBar: topAppBar,
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        height: 55.0,
        child: BottomAppBar(
          color: Color.fromRGBO(58, 66, 86, 1.0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.white),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(_AnimatedNavigation(Main()));
                  }
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            _items.isNotEmpty
                ? Expanded(
              child: GridView.builder(
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                ),
                itemCount: _items.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      RawMaterialButton(
                        child: Image(
                          image: NetworkImage(_items[index]["portrait"]),
                          height: 190,
                          width: 150,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.push(context, _AnimatedNavigation(SpecificCharacterRoute(
                              _items[index]["name"], _items[index]["full_name"], _items[index]["shop_background"], _items[index]["overview"],
                              _items[index]["difficulty"], "images/dbdkillerlogo.png")
                          )
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              ),
            )
                : Container(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i tried some other things but most of the time i couldnt get to my list even

this is the json im decoding:

```
{
   "killers": [
       {
          "_id":"5f47fdbad80cf12dc4ac06c4",
          "name":"Nurse",
          "name_tag":"NR",
          "full_name":"Sally Smithson",
          "alias":"",
          "gender":"Female",
          "nationality":"Anglo-American",
          "realm":"Crotus Prenn Asylum",
          "power":"Spencer's Last Breath",
          "weapon":"The Bonesaw",
          "speed":"96.25 % | 3.85 m/s",
          "terror_radius":"32",
          "height":"Average",
          "voice_actor":"Anais Renevey",
          "difficulty":"Hard",
          "overview":"The Nurse is a warping Killer, able to blink through obstacles and quickly close gaps with her Power.\n\nHer personal Perks, Stridor, Thanatophobia, and A Nurse's Calling, allow her to decrease Survivor abilities and track them when they are injured.\n\nShe is focused on spotting and tracking, making it harder for Survivors to hide.",
          "lore":"Sally Smithson came to town with dreams of children's feet and laughter in a wooden home built by her husband Andrew. But life came not with smiles but with plans of destruction. Andrew worked as a lumberjack - a job with its perils. One day, Andrew's foreman had to pay Sally a visit, forever changing her life. She was alone.\n\nWithout food on the table and no other option, Sally had to find a way, but the only employment she could get was at the Crotus Prenn Asylum. Nobody sought employment there unless they were in dire need. Just like Sally. Without any education, she started at the bottom, doing the hard night shift.\n\nOver the years, her mind had reached its limits, two decades of seeing horrid things that violate the eyes. Memories that are re-played every night. Being abused verbally and physically, by people without limits. Sally saw insanity from the outside, just to catch it herself.\n\nFinally she could not take it any more and concepts of purification emerged inside her. She did what she felt was necessary. As the morning staff arrived one day in September - they found over fifty dead patients, lifeless, in their bed along four staff members, also dead.\n\nOnly Sally had survived the night, but her mind was gone, rocking back and forth non-stop. Exactly what happened is only known by her, but it seems that some of them had been choked as they had marks around their necks. They got her into an ambulance, but that ambulance never reached the hospital. It was found crashed in a nearby wood, all the staff dead and Sally nowhere to be found.",
          "dlc":"The Last Breath Chapter",
          "dlc_id":509060,
          "is_free":true,
          "is_ptb":false,
          "lang":"en",
             "portrait":"https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/deadbydaylight_gamepedia_en/images/3/31/K04_charSelect_portrait.png/revision/latest?cb=20200721164254",
             "preview_portrait":"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dearvoodoo/dbd/master/Killers/PreviewPortrait/NR.png",
             "shop_background":"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dearvoodoo/dbd/master/Killers/ShopBG/NR.png",
          "perks":[
             "Stridor",
             "Thanatophobia",
             "AnursesCalling"
          ]
       },
```

Comment: why are you decoding an assetImage? what are you trying to do?

Comment: And what exactly doesn't work? This might be a problem: ````final data = await json.decode(response);````. jdon.decode is not async function, you should remove ````await````

Comment: @john i edited the question for you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter image preload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51343735/flutter-image-preload)

Comment: Also, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65544157/how-to-preload-images-with-cached-network-image